# Geometry Nodes: Animating a cube array in order

Tags: geometry-nodes

Seems like the tutorials I've been testing are missing on some possible basic concepts that I need help with.  I'd like to create a Geometry node that reveals one cube at a time in an animation in the exact order I have listed below in the attached image. Not important at the moment but I'd like to test this a bit and understand the logic if I needed to use it for other sort orders.

[image]

Update so the solution by @Chris seems to do mostly what I need and reversing direction isn't too hard. The only issue I'm finding is where and what nodes to add to get the position of each new instance of each new box as it's created. I wanted to use that to move other objects around.  Tried sample index, field at index... I might have to create another thread for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

Comment: I might accept that as the final answer but it's going in the opposite direction. I see in your video you're viewing the camera from the opposite direction. I can also see your X axis on the top right is positive left. Would you know how to correct this?

Comment: I am sure you are intelligent enough to change that direction on your own! Good luck and happy blending!